# Laravel copy data to other table, check if exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller, copy, file-exists

I want to copy many row to another table

table **TEMPORARY DATA**

```
| id | name |  email     | id_transaction | order_number |
|----|------|------------|----------------|--------------|
| 1  | Gery | a@mail.com | A1             | 1            |
| 2  | Ray  | b@mail.com | A1             | 2            |
```

I want to copy these rows to table **MAIN DATA**

```
| id | name | email | id_transaction | order_number |
```

I want to check if `id_transaction` and `order_number` exists, the row will not copy to MAIN DATA.

This is what i've tried so far, but it's only copying the first row from `id _transaction`

```
| 1 | Gery | a@mail.com | A1 | 1 |
```

```
$copy = TEMPORARYDATA::where('id_transaction', '=', $id_trans )->get()->toArray();
foreach ($copy as $copy) 
{
    $count = MAINDATA::where('id_transaction', $id_trans)->groupby('order_num')->count('order_num');
    if ($count > 0)
    {}
    else
    {
        $save_copy = array_except($copy, ['created_at', 'updated_at','id']);
        MAINDATA::insert($save_copy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `id` of the record you wish to copy (if you don't care it) or change it. I also suggest you to return the value of `$copy` to have an idea of how that variable is filled, and, if it isn't filled as you expected, use `toSql()` to output the query you're executing.

Anyway, you should count `MAINDATA` records, **outside** `for` loop, 'cause you're repeating the same query many times, that's useless and a waste of resources of your machine.

The code you provided should be:

```
$copy = TEMPORARYDATA::select('name', 'email', 'id_transaction', 'order_number')
                     ->where('id_transaction', '=', $id_trans )
                     ->get()
                     ->toArray();

$count = MAINDATA::where('id_transaction', $id_trans)
                 ->groupby('order_num')
                 ->count();

foreach ($c as $copy) 
{
    if ($count > 0)
        ;
    else
        MAINDATA::insert($c);
}
```

**N.B.:** make sure properties you're trying to insert in table are in `protected $fillable` array in your model. Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code for transfer TEMPORARY DATA table to MAIN DATA table and your condition also satisfied.
$temporary_Data = [];

`$temporary_Data = TEMPORARYDATA::where('id_transaction', '=', $id_trans )->get()

foreach($temporary_Data as $data)
{
   `$mainObj =['name' => $temporary_Data->name,
'email' => $temporary_Data->email,
'id_transaction'=> $temporary_Data->id_transaction,
'order_number'=> $temporary_Data->order_number,]`
   MAINDATA::create($data);
}`